# Allow user to load file into (and invoke) Lambda function without granting AWS access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

What is the best way to load an Excel file (or csv,etc) into (and thus invoking) an AWS lambda function without the person performing the upload having access to AWS.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create an S3 bucket, and use a front end web page to allow a user to upload the file to S3 directly (no lambda needed) via html form (plenty of tutorials how to do this).

You then need to setup your lambda to be invoked on the S3 event `ObjectCreated:Put`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

This will send an event to lambda with the objects location in S3. You can then use the aws sdk in lambda to call S3 can get the file/object and do whatever processing you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Can use an API-Gateway attaching the lambda and use the API link to upload the file.

User will select and upload the file using the html form which you have to create.

html form code

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="iFile" placeholder="Upload logo file">
```

Use JQuery ajax to call the API

```
var form = $('#hfrm').get(0); 
var formData = new FormData(form);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "URL");
xhr.send(formData);
```

Use the below lambda code

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

flds = parseFormFields(event, s3, "S3 bucket Name", "Path to file")


def parseFormFields(event, s3, bucket, path):

post_data               = base64.b64decode(event['body'])
decoded_elements    = []
elements                    = post_data.split(b'\r\n')

for element in elements:
    if len(element) > 0:
        try:
            decoded_elements.append(element.decode())
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            decoded_elements.append(element)

print(decoded_elements)

header                      = decoded_elements[0]
header_positions    = []

for i in range(len(decoded_elements)):
    if isinstance(decoded_elements[i], str) and decoded_elements[i] == header:
        header_positions.append(i)

form_fields = {}

for header_position in header_positions:
    
    if decoded_elements[header_position +1 ].find('filename="') > 0 and decoded_elements[header_position +1 ].find('filename=""') < 0:
        
        file_name = decoded_elements[header_position + 1][decoded_elements[header_position + 1].find('filename="') + 10:len(decoded_elements[header_position + 1]) - 1]
        file_ext = file_name[file_name.rfind("."):]
        field_name = decoded_elements[header_position + 1][decoded_elements[header_position + 1].find('name="') + 6:decoded_elements[header_position + 1].find('filename="') - 3]
        
        file_type = decoded_elements[header_position + 2][decoded_elements[header_position + 2].find(':') + 2:]
        contents    = []
        if isinstance(decoded_elements[header_position + 3], bytes):
            contents.append(decoded_elements[header_position + 3])
        else:
            contents.append(bytes(decoded_elements[header_position + 3], 'utf-8'))

        i               = header_position + 4           
        while isinstance(decoded_elements[i], bytes) or decoded_elements[i].find(header) < 0:
            print(f'{file_name} - Extra line')
            contents.append(b'\r\n')
            if isinstance(decoded_elements[i], bytes):
                contents.append(decoded_elements[i])
            else:
                contents.append(bytes(decoded_elements[i], 'utf-8'))
            i = i + 1
        
        file_content = b"".join(contents)
        
        file_name = f'{int(time.time()*1000000)}{file_ext}'
        s3.put_object(Body=file_content, Bucket=bucket, Key=f'{path}/{file_name}', ContentType=file_type)
        filePath = f's3://{bucket}/{path}/{file_name}'
        form_fields[field_name] = filePath                      
    else:
        
        field_name = decoded_elements[header_position + 1][decoded_elements[header_position + 1].find('name="') + 6:len(decoded_elements[header_position + 1]) - 1]
        if decoded_elements[header_position + 2].find(header) < 0:
            field_values = [decoded_elements[header_position + 2]]
            field_value = "\n"
            i               = header_position + 3
            while decoded_elements[i].find(header) < 0:
                print(f'{field_name} - Extra line')
                field_values.append(decoded_elements[i])
                i = i + 1
            field_value = field_value.join(field_values)
            form_fields[field_name] = field_value
        else:
            form_fields[field_name] = ""
print(form_fields)
return form_fields
```